# I am trying to target/select elements in a different parent with CSS

Tags: css

Take a look at the code below...

As you can see the 'HAZEL(NUT)' and 'HASSEL(NØD)' has a different parent to the checkbox. Which is why I think the checkbox *works* for the font-weight part, but *doesn't* work for selecting #hazelnut or #hasselnod. If anyone could help me with the correct selector for #hazelnut and #hasselnod I would be very grateful.

Hope this is clear, I'm quite a newbie to HTML and CSS, so have trouble explaining what I mean sometimes!

HTML here:

```
<div class="container" id="lang">
<input type="radio" id="english" name="language" value="english" checked="checked" /> 
<input type="radio" id="dansk" name="language" value="dansk" />
<ul>
<label for="english"><li id="en">ENGLISH</li></label>
<label for="dansk"><li id="dk">DANSK</li></label>
</ul> 
</div>

<div class="container" id="myname">
<h1 id="hazelnut">HAZEL<br>(NUT)</h1>
<h1 id="hasselnod">HASSEL<br>(NØD)</h1>
</div>
```

CSS here:

```
#dansk:checked ~ * #dk {
    font-weight: 700; 
}

#dansk:checked ~ * #en {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#dansk:checked * #hazelnut {
    display: none;
}

#english:checked ~ * #en {
    font-weight: 700; 
}

#english:checked ~ * #dk {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#english:checked * #hasselnod {
    display: none; 
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, for the `~` selector to work, the elements must have the same parent. As I see it, I'm afraid you'll have to involve some javascript in here.

What I'd do, is have the radio buttons change a data attribute of `#lang`, so it would be transparent to the css:

```
<div id="lang" data-value="en">
```

and then use the following css rules:

```
/*when #myname is preceded by #lang with data-value attribute 'en',
 select direct child #hasselnod */
#lang[data-value='en'] ~ #myname > #hasselnod {
    /* and set its display to none*/
    display: none; 
}
```

Now, we'll need the javascript to change the `data-value` attribute of `#lang`. Look at the onclick function in the following snippet:

```
<input type="radio" id="dansk" name="language" value="dansk"
      onclick="this.parentNode.setAttribute('data-value', 'da')" />
```

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wkL7q/2/

Comment: `~` is the [General sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators), not the [before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) selector FYI... Regardless though, your answer is good

Comment: An unneeded and confusing over-simplification, indeed. removed.

Answer (score 0):

To target elements in a different parent, I think you need to use jQuery:

```
$("#lang input").change(function () {
    var lang = $(this).val();
    if(lang == 'dansk') {
        $('#hazelnut').hide();
        $('#hasselnod').show();
    } else {
        $('#hazelnut').show();
        $('#hasselnod').hide();
    }
});
```

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X3ZtK/